# OpenGL texture tiling does not work properly

Tags: opengl, texture-mapping

I try to tile texture with size 16x16 inside rectangle 100x100. I set `GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S` and `GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T` to `GL_REPEAT` but it gives no effect (see image below). How to tile image properly? Should I use different method for drawing instead of `glDrawArrays`?

Original texture 16x16

[image: Original texture 16x16]

Actual result:

[image: Actual result]

Code:

```
glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
glHint(GL_LINE_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_NICEST);
glEnable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH);
glHint(GL_POINT_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_NICEST);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture.getId());
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP, GL_TRUE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

// GL_REPEAT
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

glPushMatrix();
glVertexPointer(VERTEX_POINTER_COUNT, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexPointer);
glColorPointer(COLOR_POINTER_COUNT, GL_FLOAT, 0, colorPointer);
glTexCoordPointer(TEXTURE_COORD_POINTER_COUNT, GL_FLOAT, 0, texCoordPointer);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
glPopMatrix();

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, NULL_ID);
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glDisable(GL_BLEND);
```

UPD.

```
// Texture coordinates
private float[] uv = new float[]{0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0};
public final FloatBuffer texCoordPointer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(2 * 3 * 2 * 2);
texCoordPointer.clear();
texCoordPointer.put(uv[0]).put(uv[1]);
texCoordPointer.put(uv[2]).put(uv[3]);
texCoordPointer.put(uv[4]).put(uv[5]);
texCoordPointer.put(uv[0]).put(uv[1]);
texCoordPointer.put(uv[4]).put(uv[5]);
texCoordPointer.put(uv[6]).put(uv[7]);
texCoordPointer.flip();
```

Comment: What's the range of your texture coordinates?

Comment: @KolesnikovichDmitry: He said "texture coordinates", not positions. The stuff in `texCoordPointer`, not in `vertexPointer`.

Comment: @RetoKoradi see UPD in question please

Comment: You've done this correctly, but described it incorrectly. _"I set `GL_REPEAT` to `GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S` and `GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T`."_ You actually set the S and T wrap states to repeat, not the other way around.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman thanks fixed

Comment: Your update shows something different than you described. Those UV coordinates are in the range [**0.0**,**1.0**], which is why you see only one copy of the image. Where are the numbers **20** and **120** mentioned earlier coming from?

Comment: Yes, if you want the texture repeated for example 6 times, your texture coordinates should be in the range [0.0, 6.0].

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman 20 and 120 - this is `vertexPointer`

Comment: @RetoKoradi `uv = new float[]{0, 0, 0, 6, 6, 6, 6, 0}; ` works for me. You can leave it as an answer

Comment: @RetoKoradi How should I set `texCoordPointer` if my texture is not file with `uv = {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0}` but region in atlas with `uv = {0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0}`?

Comment: @KolesnikovichDmitry: That is a very different question. And it should be asked by asking a new question, not in a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the texture repeated for example 6 times, your texture coordinates should be in the range [0.0, 6.0]